# Need Help/Advice Crypto Websocket Rest

Tags: python, websocket

You can find the commit on this link to github [text](https://github.com/37trillion/RSICryptoCom)

I have a four file crypto.com/exchange trading software it is not operating how i want it to! It connects to the websocket and sends a heartbeat back to the exchange! However it disconnects after a few hours like 5 or 6 without making any trades?
I am making the RSICryptoCom Bot as a personal project with what i have learned from a python course and what AI has provided me!
I get an error on initial statement cant not get websocket market data as error! The rest of the code apparently is fine! Im pretty sure without being able to get market data the trading automation has nothing to trade or implement the trade_strategy.py file from!
How do i connect the Trade_Strategy.py file to the main.py file and the CryptoCom.py file together and automate trades based on RSI strategy?

main.py file

```
import requests
import time
import logging
import hashlib
import hmac
import json
import websocket
from CryptoCom import CryptoComAPI
from trade_strategy import TradeStrategy
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from logging_component import setup_logger

# Set your API key and secret key
API_KEY = 'place your api_key here'
SECRET_KEY = "place your secret_key here"

# Set the symbol and interval for the candlestick data
SYMBOL = "CRO_USD"
INTERVAL = "1m"

# Set the trade strategy parameters
STRATEGY_PARAMS = {
    "buy_threshold": 0.5,
    "sell_threshold": -0.5,
    "stop_loss": -5,
}

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

def authenticate(ws):
    """Authenticate the websocket connection"""
    timestamp = str(api.time()["result"])
    signature = hmac.new(SECRET_KEY.encode(), timestamp.encode(), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    ws.send('{"id": 2, "method": "public/auth", "params": {"api_key": "%s", "timestamp": "%s", "sign": "%s"}}'
            % (API_KEY, timestamp, signature))

def subscribe(ws):
    """Subscribe to the specified symbol's candlestick data"""
    ws.send('{"id": 3, "method": "public/subscribe", "params": {"channels": ["kline.%s"]}}' % SYMBOL)
    logging.INFO(f"{subscribe} status")

def on_message(ws, message):
    """Callback function for incoming websocket messages"""
    logging.info(f"Received message: {message}")
    if message:
        message_json = json.loads(message)
        if message_json and message_json.get('id'):
            request_id = message_json['id']
            response = requests.get(request_id)
            if response:
                response['result'] = message_json.get('result')
                response['error'] = message_json.get('error')
                response['status'] = 'done'
                logging.info(f"Response received for request id: {request_id}")
                del requests[request_id]
        else:
            logging.warning(f"Unrecognized WebSocket message: {message_json}")
    else:
        logging.warning("Received an empty message from WebSocket server.")


def on_open(ws):
    """Callback function for websocket connection"""
    logging.info("Websocket opened")
    subscribe(ws)

def on_message(ws, message):
    """Callback function for websocket messages"""
    logging.info(message)
    data = json.loads(message)
    # Handle authentication response
    if "result" in data and data["id"] == 2:
        if data["result"]:
            logging.info("Authentication successful")
        else:
            logging.error("Authentication failed")
            ws.close()
    # Handle subscription response
    elif "result" in data and data["id"] == 3:
        if data["result"]:
            logging.info("Subscription successful")
        else:
            logging.error("Subscription failed")
            ws.close()
    # Handle incoming data using the trade strategy object
    else:
        strategy.handle_message(message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    """Callback function for websocket errors"""
    logging.error(error)

def on_close(ws):
    """Callback function for websocket close"""
    logging.info("Websocket closed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    api = CryptoComAPI(API_KEY, SECRET_KEY)

# Connect to WebSocket and start listening for messages
    api_ws = CryptoComAPI(api, ['trade.CRO_USD'], api.parse_ws_message)
    api_ws.connect()

    # Create the TradeStrategy object
    strategy = TradeStrategy(api, SYMBOL, INTERVAL, STRATEGY_PARAMS)

    # Connect to the websocket
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://stream.crypto.com/v2/market",
                                on_open=on_open,
                                on_message=None,
                                on_error=on_error,
                                on_close=None,
                                keep_running=True)

    ws.run_forever()
    # Keep running the websocket connection
    while True:
        try:
            ws.run_forever()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            ws.close()
            break
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Websocket error: {e}")
            logging.info("Retrying in 5 seconds...")
            time.sleep(5)
```

trade_strategy.py

```
import logging
from CryptoCom import CryptoComAPI
from ta.momentum import RSIIndicator
import time
class TradeStrategy:
    def __init__(self, api, symbol, interval, params):
        self.api = api
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.interval = interval
        self.buy_threshold = params.get("buy_threshold", 0.5)
        self.sell_threshold = params.get("sell_threshold", -0.5)
        self.stop_loss = params.get("stop_loss", -5)
        self.rsi_period = params.get("rsi_period", 14)
        self.rsi_upper = params.get("rsi_upper", 70)
        self.rsi_lower = params.get("rsi_lower", 30)
        self.last_price = None
        self.last_bid_price = None
        self.last_ask_price = None
        self.last_rsi = None
        self.order_id = None
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    def handle_message(self, message):
        data = self.api.parse_ws_message(message)
        if data.get("method") == "kline.update":
            self.process_kline_update(data.get("params"))
        elif data.get("method") == "trade":
            self.process_trade(data.get("params"))

    def process_kline_update(self, params):
        if params.get("symbol") != self.symbol or params.get("interval") != self.interval:
            return
        candle = params.get("data")[0]
        close_price = float(candle.get("c"))
        bid_price = float(candle.get("b"))
        ask_price = float(candle.get("a"))
        if self.last_price is None:
            self.last_price = close_price
        if self.last_bid_price is None:
            self.last_bid_price = bid_price
        if self.last_ask_price is None:
            self.last_ask_price = ask_price
        rsi = self.calculate_rsi(close_price)
        self.logger.info("Close price: {:.8f}, Bid price: {:.8f}, Ask price: {:.8f}, RSI: {:.2f}".format(close_price, bid_price, ask_price, rsi))
        if rsi is not None and self.last_rsi is not None:
            if self.last_rsi < self.rsi_upper and rsi >= self.rsi_upper and close_price > self.last_price and ask_price <= self.last_bid_price:
                self.logger.info("RSI crossover upper threshold, executing sell order")
                self.sell(ask_price)
            elif self.last_rsi > self.rsi_lower and rsi <= self.rsi_lower and close_price < self.last_price and bid_price >= self.last_ask_price:
                self.logger.info("RSI crossover lower threshold, executing buy order")
                self.buy(bid_price)
        self.last_price = close_price
        self.last_bid_price = bid_price
        self.last_ask_price = ask_price
        self.last_rsi = rsi

    def process_trade(self, params):
        if params.get("symbol") != self.symbol:
            return
        price = float(params.get("p"))
        if params.get("s") == "buy":
            self.logger.info("Buy order executed at {:.8f}".format(price))
            self.order_id = None
        elif params.get("s") == "sell":
            self.logger.info("Sell order executed at {:.8f}".format(price))
            self.order_id = None

    def calculate_rsi(self, close_price):
        rsi = RSIIndicator(close_price, self.rsi_period)
        return rsi.rsi()

    def execute_strategy(self, candles):
        close_price = [float(candle["close"]) for candle in candles]
        rsi = self.calculate_rsi(close_price)
        last_rsi = rsi[-1]
        logging.info(f"RSI: {last_rsi:.2f}")

        if last_rsi > self.rsi_upper:
            # Sell signal
            if self.api.has_position(self.symbol):
                response = self.api.close_position(
                    self.symbol, type="limit", price=self.api.get_ticker_price(self.symbol)
                )
                logging.info(f"Closed position: {response}")
            else:
                logging.info("No position to close")

        elif last_rsi < self.buy_threshold:
            # Buy signal
            if not self.api.has_position(self.symbol):
                response = self.api.open_position(
                    self.symbol, "buy", type="limit", price=self.api.get_ticker_price(self.symbol)
                )
                logging.info(f"Opened position: {response}")
            else:
                logging.info("Already has position")
        else:
            logging.info("No signal")

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                candles = self.api.get_candles(self.symbol, self.interval)
                if candles:
                    self.execute_strategy(candles)
            except Exception as e:
                logging.exception(f"Error occurred: {e}")
            time.sleep(60) # Wait for 1 minute before running again
```

CryptoCom.py

```
import hmac
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import hashlib
import time

class CryptoComAPI:
    
    def __init__(self, api_key, api_secret, api_url='https://api.crypto.com/v2/'):
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.api_secret = api_secret
        self.api_url = api_url

    def _generate_signature(self, params):
        params_str = ''
        for key in sorted(params.keys()):
            params_str += str(key) + str(params[key])
        signature = hmac.new(bytes(self.api_secret, 'utf-8'), 
                             bytes(params_str, 'utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
        logging.INFO(f"the {_generate_signature} status is {message}")
        logging._Level(f"{INFO}")
        return signature
    
    def _request(self, method, path, **kwargs):
        url = urljoin(self.api_url, path)
        params = kwargs.get('params', {})
        params['api_key'] = self.api_key
        params['timestamp'] = int(time.time() * 1000)
        kwargs['params'] = params
        kwargs['headers'] = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-MBX-APIKEY': self.api_key,
        }
        kwargs['params']['signature'] = self._generate_signature(params)
        response = requests.request(method, url, **kwargs)
        response.raise_for_status()
        return response.json()

    def connect(self):
        # Test connection
        try:
            self._request('GET', 'public/get-instruments')
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Connection failed: {e}")
            return False
        logging.info("Connection successful.")
        return True

    def get_instruments(self):
        response = self._request('GET', 'public/get-instruments')
        return response['result']

    def get_open_orders(self, symbol):
        params = {'instrument_name': symbol}
        
        response = self._request('GET', 'private/get-open-orders', params=params)
        logging.INFO(f"The {get_open_orders} status is {message}")
        return response['result']['orders']
    
    def place_order(self, symbol, side, price, quantity):
        params = {
            'instrument_name': symbol,
            'side': side,
            'price': price,
            'quantity': quantity,
            'type': 'LIMIT',
            'time_in_force': 'GOOD_TILL_CANCEL',
        }
        
        response = self._request('POST', 'private/create-order', json=params)
        logging.INFO(f"the {place_order} status is {message}")
        return response['result']['order_id']
    
    def cancel_order(self, symbol, order_id):
        params = {
            'instrument_name': symbol,
            'order_id': order_id,
        }
        response = self._request('DELETE', 'private/cancel-order', json=params)
        return response['result']['order_id']
    def parse_ws_message(self, message):
        """
        Parses WebSocket message received from Crypto.com exchange.
        """
        message = json.loads(message)
        if 'e' in message:
            # This is a response to a subscription request.
            if message['e'] == 'subscribe':
                if message['success']:
                    logging.info(f"Subscription to {message['stream']} successful.")
                else:
                    logging.error(f"Subscription to {message['stream']} failed: {message['message']}")
            # This is a regular data update message.
            elif message['e'] == 'update':
                # Do something with the data.
                pass
        else:
            logging.warning(f"Unrecognized WebSocket message: {message}")
```

how do i debug and edit these files there is one more file the logger.py file however im trying to connect all the files together and automate the trading based on the trade_Strategy.py file i get a websocket market data error! and then the websocket heart beats start to interact but i get no trading over a six hour period
any help is much appreciated!
Thanks in adavance

I have tried building a market_websocket.py file and connecting it that way i have tried to reform the code and edit it to make automated trading a thing on crypto.com/exchange
i am expecting a automated trading system to leave the python file running by starting it from the main.py file and having the trade_Strategy.py file executing trades based on strategy
I get a websocekt error can not get market data and then the heart beat starts to send back and forth but no trading is execute until disconnect 6 hours later

Comment: I applaud your drive!